# Show that $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $F(x):=\int_{(-\infty,x]}fdm$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be measurable with $\int_{\mathbb{R}}fdm<\infty$. Show that $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $F(x):=\int_{(-\infty,x]}fdm$ is continuous.

Do I need to consider the case where $f$ is bounded?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use your favorite convergence theorem on $\int_x^{x+h} f$ for $h\to 0$.

Comment: You need to assume something on your measure $m$. If your measure is of the form 
$$
m(E) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } 0 \in E \\ 0 & \text{ if not} \end{cases}
$$
then the result is false because $F$ will have a discontinuity at $0$ in general. (In fact, $\int f \, dm = f(0)$ in this case, so you will have a discontinuity at $0$ if and only if $f(0) \neq 0$.)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I am pretty sure op meant the Lebesgue measure... but you are of course correct.

Comment: @user251257 : How are you sure? From the answers? He's not the one who wrote them. And it is very non-standard to denote the Lebesgue measure with the letter $m$, the usual notation I've seen was $\lambda$, and even then I would define it ; when speaking of such "probability-theory-lookalike" statements, the chosen measure is never obvious.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva notation for the Lebesgue measure varies. But I have seen $dm$ quite a lot.

Comment: @user251257 : Fair enough. But on a website like this, the OP should add 'Lebesgue-measurable' for the sake of clarity.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva please take the tags into account. But in general I agree with you.

Comment: @user251257 : aaaaaah. I missed the tags! My bad!

Comment: Some part of my answer that you guys found unsatisfactory??

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $x_n \to x^+.$ Then

$$|F(x_n) - F(x)| = |\int_x^{x_n} f| \le \int_x^{x_n} |f| = \int_{\mathbb R}|f|\chi_{(x,x_n)}.$$

The integrands on the right $\to 0$ pointwise everywhere, and are bounded above on $\mathbb R$ by $|f|\in L^1(\mathbb R).$ By the DCT, $|F(x_n) - F(x)| \to 0.$ Thus $F$ is continuous from the right. The proof from the left is similar.

Answer (score 2):

Consequence of absolute continuity of Lebesgue integral.

**Lemma** Let $f : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue integrable function. Then for every $\epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that
$$
\mu(E) < \delta \implies \int_{E}|f|d\mu < \epsilon.
$$

Let us first see how the lemma implies the result you are asking.
$$
|F(x) - F(y)| = \left|\int_{(x,y]} fd\mu\right| \leq \int_{(x,y]}|f|d\mu<\epsilon
$$
whenever $\mu((x,y]) = |y-x|<\delta$. We will now conclude by proving the lemma.

**Proof of Lemma** Let $E_n$ be a nested sequence of sets defined via:
$$
E_n = \{x : |f(x)|\leq n\}.
$$
Clearly, $0\leq \underbrace{|f|\mathcal{X}_{E_n}}_{=g_n}\nearrow |f|$. Thus by monotone convergence theorem,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int g_n d\mu = \int fd\mu.
$$
Take $N$ large enough so that
$$
\int (f-g_N) d\mu < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.
$$
Now,
$$
\int_E f d\mu = \underbrace{\int_E (f-g_N) d\mu}_{<\frac{\epsilon}{2}} + \underbrace{\int_E g_N d\mu}_{\leq N \mu(E)}.
$$
It suffices to pick $\delta$ so that $N\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. It proves the lemma. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

Since f is a nonnegative by definition of the Lebesgue integral $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there exists $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that h is bounded, measurable, nonnegative, finite support, $h \leq f$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, and 
$\int_{\mathbb{R}}{|f-h|} < \epsilon$.

WLOG assume $y<x$
Consider $|F(x)-F(y)|=|\int_{y}^{x}{f dm}| \leq \int_{y}^{x}{|f-h|} + \int_{y}^{x}{|h|} < \epsilon + \int_{y}^{x}{|h|}$. Now, h is bounded so $\exists M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|h| \leq M$ for all x. Select $\delta = \epsilon / M$.

Then you have that $\int_{y}^{x}{|h|} \leq M |x-y| < M \delta = \epsilon$. Hence, you have that $|F(x)-F(y)| < 2 \epsilon$ i.e is continuous.